# Inference from generic situation S

Tags: prolog

I hope that someone can help me. Is it possible inference from a situation `S` different to `s0` in Prolog?

I have a `s0` (initial situation) like this:

```
isoven(oven).
isoff(oven,s0).
ison(X,do(a,S)):- a=switchOn(X),isoven(X); isOff(X,S),\+ a=swicthOff(X). (fluent inon)
```

If I prompted:

```
?- isOn(oven,s0).
false.

?- ison(oven,do(swicth(oven)s0)).
true
```

It would be nice if existed a command like "save(do(swicth(oven)s0)) to S'" in order to obtained a result like this:

```
?- ison(oven,S').
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

Prolog is not magic, you need to implement things properly. 
It appears you want to use situation calculus, there's plenty of material online about it.

Also:

```
a=switchOn(X)
```

This is meaningless, it always fail. You need a variable there (the first letter must be upper case)